# Galleria Flickr photo descriptions

Tags: json, flickr, galleria, field-description

I've gotten Galleria.io to return different photo albums from Flickr, but it doesn't seem to fetch the description of the photos for display. Is there a way to do this in Galleria.io?

If not, is there a way to fetch a JSON feed directly from Flickr that contains the description info?

I've noticed that the JSON response coming from Flickr via Galleria seems to include the description, yet it does not show in the gallery. Here's a snippet of the response:

```
..."isfriend":0,"isfamily":0,"description":{"_content":"Pool deck."},"url_t":"htt...
```

You can seen description is in there... now how to make it show up in galleria...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer at the bottom of this page: http://docs.galleria.io/article/47-flickr

Just have to add the 'description:true' flag to the flickrOptions:

```
Galleria.run('.galleria', {
        flickr: 'set:' + id,
        flickrOptions: {
            sort: 'date-posted-asc',
            description:true
        }
    });
```